# What is correct to say: "I don't like it when ..." OR "I don't like when ..."?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

Very simple question. Which is correct to say:

> 1. I don't like it when ...
> 2. I don't like when ...

Is there a difference?

For example:

> 1. I don't like it when people can't understand me.
> 2. I don't like when people can't understand me.

Or

> 1. I don't like it when it rains.
> 2. I don't like when it rains.

Or

> 1. I don't like it when it comes to arguing.
> 2. I don't like when it comes to arguing.

Comment: Both seem correct to me, conversationally speaking. The It is redundant in example 1 and 2. In 3, maybe the difference is context? Like one means arguing in general, the other in a specific situation?

Answer (score -1):

I think "I don't like it when" sounds more normal-ish, but it doesn't seem wrong either without the "it". :) I hope i helped.

Answer (score -1):

> I don't like it when people can't understand me.

In this sentence "IT" is being used as an empty or 'dummy' subject.  It is understood that 'it' relates to people not understanding what you are saying or doing but you are not specifying exactly what 'it' is..

It would be better phrased as: "*I don't like being misunderstood.*"

> I don't like it when it rains.

In this sentence you are using 'it' as both an empty subject and an object pronoun.  Again, this might be better phrased as: "*I don't like the rain...*"

"*when it comes to*" is an interesting phrasal verb, meaning to reach a particular state or point, especially one that is bad or unpleasant.  So:

> I don't like it when it comes to arguing.

Is probably more correct than:

> I don't like when it comes to arguing.

But I am sure you will hear both.  Again, 'I' am the object and 'it' is being used as an empty object.  However, I think this is better phrased as:

> I don't like arguing.

Comment: `It would be better phrased as: "I don't like being misunderstood."` Whoa, hard disagree. Neither is "better". They're slightly different ways of expressing more or less the same thing.

Comment: Best to hold strong opinions lightly...

Comment: exactly; it's hard to hold off on downvoting this answer because of the statement that the proffered way is 'better phrased'.

Comment: I have not said 'is' or 'must, these are merely suggestions - 'might', and my opinion -  to which I am entitled, as you are yours...